# How to show data to angular?

Tags: html, angular

list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentAPIService } from 'src/app/services/student-api.service';
import { Student } from 'src/app/model/student';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private studentAPI: StudentAPIService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.studentAPI.studentList().subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      return res;
    });

  }

}
```

list.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="center">
        <table id="student_Table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let row of res">
                <td>{{ row.student_name }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am new in angular and I want to show data in `list.component.html` table. In `ts` file I have successfully fetch data through an API and data are showing in `console.log(res)` but unable to show in table. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the variable (and it should be public) in the class definition, then assign the service response to that variable. So;

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private studentAPI: StudentAPIService ) { }

  public res: any | any[]; // you can create an interface to the data type

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.studentAPI.studentList().subscribe(res=>{
      this.res = res;
    });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use async pipe and get rid of subscribing inside component. Because async pipe will auto unsubscribe when component destroyed.

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

 response$:Observable<IStudentList[]>;
 constructor( private studentAPI: StudentAPIService ) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.response$ = this.studentAPI.studentList();
 }
}
```

Now You can iterate response$ like below..

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="center">
      <table id="student_Table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let row of response$ | async">
             <td>{{ row.student_name }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See above `<tr *ngFor="let row of response$ | async">` this is auto-subscribe and you will get your list data in html and iterate over it and display it.